# Tables, rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is my code about this table attached. I have a problem because my table is not how I wanted. I am beginner in html5 and I really have troubles with rowspan and colspan. Any tricks to learn better about rowspan and colspan and how can I do the table how I want.

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Hi</th>
    <th>Hi</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>hi</td>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: When using rowspan and colspan in HTML5 you should also use `rowgroup` and `colgroup`, and also use `scope="[row|col|rowgroup|colgroup]"` — see [Tables with irregular headers](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/)

Comment: As I said I'm still a beginner so.. @StephenP

Comment: "…still a beginner" that's why I'm pointing out this article — best time to learn these [a11y](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a11y) bits is when you're starting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `colspan` for the last cell in the header and the last cell in the first row of the table body otherwise column sum will be only 3 for them(based on colspan).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    table,
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #666;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Assignment 4</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Hi</th>
      <th colspan="2">Hi</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hi</td>
      <td>Hi</td>
      <td colspan="2">hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hi</td>
      <td>Hi</td>
      <td>hi</td>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Hi</th>
    <th colspan="2">Hi</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td >Hi</td>
    <td colspan="2">hi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>hi</td>
    <td>hi</td>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

In short `colspan` and `rowspan` means merging columns or rows respectively.